# Correct way to resuse static UIViewController code for menu

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a menu button which is displayed on a few view controllers. The code that is used is added in the `UIViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method.

Rather than re-using the same boiler plate code below.

```
self.menuButtonItem.title = @"Menu2";
self.menuButtonItem.target = (MESMainNavigationController *)self.navigationController;
self.menuButtonItem.action = @selector(showMenu);
```

What is the best way to implement this?

Should it be a subclass of `UIViewController` and override the `viewDidLoad`?

OR

Should it be a `UIViewController` category. Although this will not affect ALL view controllers, just a specific set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a Category, and only `#import "UIViewController+YourCategory.h"`in the files where you need the menu button code.

Categories are more useful because you could later add it to a UITableViewController or UISplitViewController, because they are subclasses of UIViewController.

Edit: It's important to note that you can't use a category like a subclass, i.e. you can't override `viewDidLoad` from the category. You'll have to create an instance method like `-(void)setupMainMenu` and call that from all of your `UIViewController`s' `viewDidLoad` methods.

Comment: Thanks, could I not call it solely from the UIViewControllers category? I.e. make a call from the category to setupMainMenu. If I have to add the relevant call to the view controllers, it might not be as much of a pain adding the three lines. I suppose the only real benefit is having the code in one place over more...

Comment: @StuartM Categories are only for adding methods to classes, not overriding. You are correct: the benefit is DRY: don't repeat yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly where one would use subclassing. Categories are for extending classes, i.e. giving them extra methods and functionality.

You also can't declare new ivars/properties without some serious hacking in categories, which should indicate that it really doesn't suit your purpose.

Comment: I do not necessarily need a new ivar/property I can access with 'self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem'. I can set this up with a Category per the answer below, is there reasons against it in this case?

Comment: @StuartM you can subclass UIViewController for this, but you must be sure to call [super viewDidLoad] in your subclass subclass. You lose the benefit of being able to add it to other view controller subclasses, i.e. UITableViewController. You'd have to make a subclass of UITableViewController to add the customized viewDidLoad.

Comment: For this reason I think the category approach would be better here, as UITableViewController subclasses from UIViewController. Thanks for the alternate approach, ill plus one that too

Answer (score 1):

The way I implemented was to simply create a util method and pass the necessary parameters (I am not passing target and the selector assuming they'll be the same for all, but if they vary from viewController to viewController you can pass them as parameters too):

```
Utils.m:

+ (void) buildMenu:(UIViewController *) viewController
{
  viewController.menuButtonItem.title = @"Menu2";
  viewController.menuButtonItem.target = (MESMainNavigationController *)viewController.navigationController;
  viewController.menuButtonItem.action = @selector(showMenu);
}
```

and you call it like this from all your view controllers:

```
[Utils buildMenu: self];
```

Comment: Thanks, I am going to go the category route on this one, but I do like this approach too and of course it is available to any subclass then and I could pass in any parameter I need. Ill plus one this too.